# Why local file is showing corrupted after downloading using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good Afternoon,
Scenario: I am having pdf's file on local system and when user click the button, I want it to get downloaded. But after getting download the file on opening shows corrupted. While posting this query I notice the file which is getting download is of 1KB and original file size is 28KB. I didn't understand why ?
I am creating the excel file at backend and saving at user location as due to huge data it is taking a lot of time so once file is created, the user can download the file.

Below are the codes of JS .

```
function download() {
    var filename="output.pdf";
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    var fileloc="C:\\ebooks\\PDF\\abc.pdf";
    element.setAttribute('href','data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ' + 
    encodeURIComponent(fileloc));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
}
```

Original file is good. Please correct me what I am doing it wrong .

Comment: If you already know the location of a document you already have on C: ... why *download* it in the first place? What do you mean by *"local system"*? A server? Do you  understand that the Browser cannot (unless started with the dangerous flag --allow-file-access-from-files) read files from a user's disk - for obvious reasons..?

Comment: This scenario i am asking is part. PDF or excel file will be created from server and saved at a location because of large data the excel file is taking very long time then i am showing last 5 file to download after file is generated. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data:` scheme URL you are creating resolves to a *plain text document* (not a PDF) containing the **text** *C:\ebooks\PDF\abc.pdf*.

You are saving this file with a *.pdf* extension so when you try to open it, your PDF reader tries to read it as a PDF (which it isn't).

If you want to save the **contents** of the file at the path you specified then you need to:

Have the user select the file using a `<input type="file">` (because JS is not allowed access to files on the user's disk unless they select them explicitly and generating the URL using [the `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

---

If you are creating the file on the server, as you said, then there is no need to construct a `data:` scheme URL, you can just use the `https:` scheme URL that points to the file on the server.

Comment: The web application is on client machine and whenever excel file is generated as it takes much time and don't want user to wait for report generation, it will save on same machine, I am showing a status as report available to download so when user click to the download button I want that file to be picked from same machine and shown as a download to the user. @Quentin

Comment: @Nadim — You can't do that. The security policy in browsers means that you can't access local files (not even if the web server is on the same computer).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and suggesting me. I am going with API call and in backend using apache IOutils, I am copying and sending streams in response then in js using blob, downloading the file. Please give +1 to my question to make Zero and may be it will be helpful for anyone.